# Is my Roses rooting

Tags: roses

I have a rose from a dear friend's funeral, it is 3 weeks old and I have it in a glass of water on my kitchen window; today I have noticed it has some side shoots; also it appears to have a root 2cm from the bottom of the stem. What are the chances that it will develop a good root stock? [image]

Comment: I would say good